# Http post returns no respose and there is no error in the request in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

i am given a task to create basic CRUD app.
I am trying to insert a text using http post, but there is no data in the success method.

```
   $http({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',
    data: {  
                   Id: '201414',
                   Note: 'sample',
                           },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' } 

})
. success(function(response) {
       console.log(response); //Returns Empty
} );
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your server method returning something.

Comment: What about your server-side part? What's the content of POST request? If you're using PHP you can see it via `var_dump( $_POST );`

Comment: debug on server side and try to pass the dummy data first then checkout with your genuine code.

Answer (score 1):

If the server method should return a value but doesn't, probably an error occurred server-side. This error however is not passed as an argument to the success handler and doesn't throw an error in the request.

You can find out if an error occurred by attaching an error handler to the  [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) call.

Try the following:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {  
        Id: '201414',
        Note: 'sample'
    }
})
.success((data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: there is no error . the api description Body Parameters -string. May be the way i am passing data is wrong?

Comment: According to the docs, there is no dataType property to set and the default header for POST requests is already "application/json". Try my updated answer.

Comment: tried that still nothing: here is  config.header - Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"Content-Type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: I expanded the success callback. Have a look at what the server is returning. If the success callback is hit then the response was OK, but the server isn't returning anything (or not in the correct JSON format). Try returning some dummy data for debugging purposes.

Comment: I dont have server access